# python Flask does not inherit template

Tags: html, flask

i am learning the template inheritance. I was trying to do it but does not work. i tried; changing location of the file, name of the file, the code itself but still not working. Other flask properties works fine.

Deneme.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("go.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

go.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <title>Template Inheritance</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1> This heading is common in all webpages </h1>
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}

  </body>
</html>
```

side.html:

```
{% extends "go.html" %}
{% block content %}
  
<h1>Welcome to Home</h1>
  
{% endblock %}
```

[output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xadeu.png)

both html files are in the template folder. i think it is not about code.
what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line of code of your view function:

```
return render_template("go.html")
```

You are returning `go.html`. You need to return `side.html` which extends the `go.html` file. Make it:

```
return render_template("side.html")
```